# Why does embedding a View Controller in a Navigation Controller, then in a Tab Bar Controller attach the nav bar to the Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

Back when I first created the foundational layout for the app I'm currently working on in Storyboard, I did it in two steps:

1. Selected my View Controller and used Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller.
2. Selected my View Controller again and used Editor->Embed In->Tab Bar Controller.

This was the resulting layout:

**Question 1:** Why do these steps create such an odd layout?

In this weird layout that seems to imply that the Navigation Controller is attached to the Tab Bar Controller as its parent, the only way I can get navigation items to display in the app (in the view controlled by the View Controller on the right) is by placing them in the nav bar of the Tab Bar Controller scene.

However, this creates various issues, including not being able to create an IBOutlet in my View Controller file for a custom view I drag into the title view slot in the Tab Bar Controller scene. Meanwhile, dragging anything into the navigation bar in the View Controller scene just makes it not appear in the app when it runs.

**Question 2:** How can I fix this layout so that I can control-drag from navigation items into my View Controller file? Or is everything actually correct, and I'm just trying to force something I shouldn't? (My intention here is to be able to set the custom title view's text in my View Controller code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its obvious, if you want to embed `MyViewController` to `NavigationController` then you need to change your second step and need to embed `NavigationController` to `Tab Bar Controller`.

1. Selected `MyViewController` and used `Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller`.
2. Selected `NavigationController` Embed with `MyViewController` and used `Editor->Embed In->Tab Bar Controller`.

It should look like this.

[image]

**Note:** You need to embed `MyViewController` to `navigationController` only if you want to perform push operation on this `TabBarItem` means with `MyViewController` other wise simply embed `MyViewController` to `TabBarController` no need to embed it with `NavigationController`.

Comment: if your VC is single in Tabbar no need to embed with Navigation controller

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Obviously OP won't add a UITabBarController at all if that was the case? Also, the question asks how to embed a navigationcontroller to the UIViewController connected to a tab, so this is the correct answer to the question.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Edited answer for this detail.

Comment: @NiravD - no no I am not tell to your answer, I commonly told, your answer is fine based on question.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I know thats why I added your suggestion in answer.

Comment: @NiravD Nice to see the positive comments here :P but the OP wants to add navigation items to the navigationbar thats the whole thing . the added note might confuse him actually lol

Comment: I redid the layout as instructed in this answer, and I now get a black screen (but no crash). I think this was actually why I did it the other way weeks ago when I first created the app. Because the app runs, but it's just a black screen. Seems like it tries to display the Navigation Controller, which isn't an actual view. Though maybe I'm wrong about that. Still, the fact remains that this layout doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Foefirelord If black screen is appearing then check that you have properly set storyboard entry point may be i think it is loss when you rebuild the UI.

Comment: @NiravD You're right. However, after adding the entry point, the app now shows my View Controller and my Tab Bar, but no Navigation Bar. It's just the contents of my View Controller starting right below the Status Bar and ending where the Tab Bar begins. Even though in Storyboard, the Navigation Bar is shown in the view controller, and I even populated it with navigation items.

Comment: @Foefirelord Can you show the screen of your storyboard so I can get what change you have made. Also show where you have set entry point in storyboard.

Comment: @NiravD I simply embedded in the order presented in the answer above, resulting in the same layout as in your screenshot. And I've set the entry point to the Tab Bar Controller. (Setting it to the View Controller or the Navigation Controller produces even worse results.) And on top of all this, my View Controller no longer has a Tab Bar Item in its hierarchy, so I can't even seem to change the text in it to nothing via Storyboard (only programmatically).

Comment: @Foefirelord If you check my screenshot tabbar item is available on NavigationController so you can change the tabbar item text from that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135927/discussion-between-foefirelord-and-nirav-d).

Comment: Had to do all sorts of adjustments to my view controller layout and my code, but this answer set me on the right track, so setting it as the correct solution.